# Facebook Login button does not trigger page refresh, FB.Event.subscribe doesn't seem to be registering

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have Login with Facebook on my site. I'm using the JS-SDK, coupled with the PHP-SDK.

I'm 99.9% sure I have all the correct files in the correct places, as the actual login works. However, I cannot get the page to fire a reload once the user has been logged in.

This is the facebook login button code ('Scope' is the new 'perms', as I just found out today):

```
<fb:login-button scope="email,user_birthday">Sign In</fb:login-button>
```

Once the user authorizes, etc, the Dialog closes, but then nothing happens. The user isn't logged in yet, and the page does not reload.

When I manually reload, the user is logged in.

This is the code I have in my footer that should listen for the login:

```
<script>
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
    });
</script>
```

In my Chrome developer tools JS console, I get an error saying "Uncaught Reference: FB is not defined". This error is there as soon as the page loads, even before the Facebook Login button is clicked.

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I've found that passing the application secret to the auth.login call causes the event to fire correctly. You can pass the application secret from PHP to the javascript function, like this:</strike>

```
<script>
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
    }, secret: '<?php print $facebook->getApiSecret(); ?>');
</script>
```

This has since been fixed by Facebook.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out and let you know!

Possible problem though: won't the secret code be visibile to anyone who looks through my source code?

Comment: That did not work for me anyway, and I checked my source and the secret is plainly visible to everyone. I don't like that.

Comment: It would, but I believe the secret is bound to the domain you specify in the application settings. I'm not sure why Facebook would otherwise expose the function getApiSecret(); in the PHP SDK.